# Mac cannot get to sleep properly

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My Macbook Pro 15" Yosemite (model 3 years ago) has a problem with sleep mode.
I even formatted the disk and reinstalled OS X.

When I click the Apple icon and choose sleep from the menu, the mouse can move around (within 3-5 pixels) but the display is not turning off.

I wait for perhaps 30 seconds, the display then goes off but the Macbook does not sleep properly. When hitting the power button, the screen shows the Apple icon with the loading bar at 80%.

The computer then freezes, I cannot do anything except force shutdown.

This occurs even when no applications are opened in that session. I have no idea how to debug or troubleshoot this problem.

Please advise.

Comment: First test would be to see if this still happens if you start up in Safe Mode [press & hold the Shift key at the chimes]. Second would be to test on a brand new admin account.

Comment: You can try and delete the sleepimage which caches sleep sessions. It's safe to delete because it recreates when you go to sleep again. The image is located at `/private/var/vm/sleepimage`. More: http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/11/sleepimage-mac/

Comment: In Safe mode, Macbook can sleep properly.
With brand new admin account, the problem still persist.
Delete sleepimage doesn't help.

Thank you for you all.

Comment: Do you have any external devices plugged in?

Comment: No it's not, i just found a problem by running AHT aka Apple Hardware Test and it shows that the RAM was broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the MEMORY is broken.

To troubleshoot this kind of problem, running the Apple Hardware Test
by pressing D or Command-D after restart the Mac OSX.